# Obtaining Friends Count And Favorites Count From User Object

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

I am having trouble obtaining `friends_count` and `favorites_count` using the `search_all_tweets` Tweepy V2 API call.

GeeksForGeeks lists `friends_count` and `favorites_count` as attributes ( https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-user-object-in-tweepy/). Unfortunately, I get an Attribute Error `raise AttributeError from None` with the last 2 lines of code.

`user.public_metrics` only consists of `followers_count`,`following_count`,`tweet_count`, and `listed_count`.

`user.entities` consist of extraneous url data.

Code is shown below:

```
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=config.BEARER_TOKEN, consumer_key=
config.CONSUMER_KEY,consumer_secret= config.CONSUMER_SECRET,access_token=
config.ACCESS_TOKEN,access_token_secret= config.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets, query=s,
                                    tweet_fields=['context_annotations','created_at', 'public_metrics','author_id', 'lang', 'geo', 'entities'], 
                                    user_fields=['username','entities','public_metrics','location','verified','description'],
                                    max_results=100, expansions='author_id'):

    for user in response.includes["users"]:
        print(user.public_metrics)
        print(user.entities)
        print(user.friends_count)
        print(user.favorites_count)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields listed by GeeksForGeeks are the User's fields in the Twitter V1 API.

There is unfortunately no way to get the number of likes of an User with the Twitter V2 API. You can try to get all his likes and count the total number of returned tweets, but that will work only if the User has only a few likes (and that will consume your monthly Tweet cap).

And friends was the previous name of followings, so the equivalent of `friends_count` in the Twitter V2 API is `following_count`. If you were looking for the mutuals, you have to get the full list of followers and the full list of followings of the user and count the number of common elements.

Finally, I would advise you to use the Twitter API documentation ([here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/user) for User objects).